# Finding Inverse of exponential function

Tags: exponential-function, inverse

$f(x)=\frac {e^{(x)}} {(1+2e^{(x)})}$

I'm having trouble finding the inverse of this function algebraically.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Factor e^x out of the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First find the inverse of the function $t/(1+2t)$.